# MongoDB - Tree Structure - Find parents with no children

Tags: mongodb, tree, children

Am storing the tree structure as

```
{_id:1, type:type1, text:xxxx}
{_id:2, type:type2, text:xxxx, ancestorIDs:[ObjectId(1)]}
{_id:3, type:type2, text:xxxx, ancestorIDs:[ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2)]}
{_id:4, type:type1, text:xxxx}
{_id:5, type:type1, text:xxxx}
```

I need to find a list of all type1 nodes which do not have any children. eg. nodes 4 & 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical pattern for your requirement involves also keeping an array of children in each of your node documents. The mongodb.org documentation provides some good examples of tree structure patterns:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

With your current design you would need to query for all nodes that are ancestors, and perform a query that has a condition like {type:type1, _id:$nin[]}. This query and the 2 step process won't yield good performance if it is required. Also, because it requires two step, you'll need to think through whether transactions are of concerned--a 2 phase commit would add additional overhead.

Therefore, the pattern is typically to also include an array of children, which allows you to quickly do a query like {type:type1, children:{$size:0}} (or you might choose to use $exists). Normally, maintaining these references yield the better trade-off as tree structures don't change frequently while query performance is more important.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Thats what I was planning to do, in case I don't find any solution.